# what is wrong with this jquery code

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Hi I am using following code for applying multiple attributes of css through jquery. My code is

```
$("div:contains('Awais')").css( {text-decoration : 'underline', cursor : 'pointer'} );
```

I get javascript error

```
missing : after property id
$("div:contains(John)").css( {text-dec...: 'underline', cursor : 'pointer'} );
```

But When I remoce `text-decoration` property the error vanishes. What is wrong with this code

Comment: Re-tagged the question. It has nothing to do with jQuery or selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-decoration` is an invalid property name unless it's enclosed in quotes as a string:

```
$("div:contains('Awais')").css( {'text-decoration' : 'underline', cursor : 'pointer'} );
```

Object properties must be enclosed in quotes unless they are valid Javascript identifiers. This is true for declarations in object literals and also for accessing using the dot notation (so `object.text-decoration` is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a hyphen unquoted in JavaScript, to modify `text-decoration` use `textDecoration`:

```
$("div:contains('Awais')").css( {textDecoration : 'underline', cursor : 'pointer'} );
```

Or quote it:

```
$("div:contains('Awais')").css( {'text-decoration' : 'underline', cursor : 'pointer'} );
```